# How to run task one last time before shutdown

Tags: java

I have a `ScheduledExecutorService` like this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(command, 0L, rate, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

At some point, I need to shut it down. But before that, I need to make sure that `command` was run one last time. Something like

```
public void shutdown() {
    executor.waitOneMoreTime();
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

How can I do that? If I do

```
public void shutdown() {
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(rate, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

my understanding is that the `command` scheduled will not be guaranteed to run again afther the `executor.shutdown()`. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
public void shutdown() {
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination (rate, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        executor.shutdown();
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        // log your error
    }
}
```

Comment: But this does not completely guarantee that the thread will be run, does it? Is it equivalent to `Thread.sleep(rate); executor.shutdown();`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
    executor.submit(command);
    executor.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    executor.shutdown();
```

The time should be adjusted to suit whatever you need for the shutdown rather than the scheduled rate.

Comment: This might work, but the problem is that at shutdown() I have no longer a reference to command, so I can't do `executor.submit(command)`

Comment: can you post more code? or maybe trying something like shutdown(command) to pass the object?